# Image Lazy Loading with picasso

Tags: android, lazy-loading, picasso

i am using Picasso to load images in my android app,but the the images i am fetching form server are very large, so is there any way to apply lazy loading using Picasso??

Comment: Lazy loading? Just wait calling `Picasso.with().into()` until the last moment you are able to - that's lazy loading. Or do you man something else?

Comment: do you mean that picasso use lazy loading by default??

Answer (score 2):

I guess picasso has not a lazy load method or something like this.

You can add a callback with methods that success and error. 
With a small progressBar that over imageview, you can tell the user that image is loading. Then you can hide the progressbar on onSuccess and onError methods.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
         .load(url)
         .into(imageView, new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess() {

               }

             @Override
             public void onError() {

              }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using picasso to load images in a recycler view the view will be created only when the view is on visible to user 
so if you use recycler view it automatically gets lazy loading
this link may help you

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview?rq=1)

Comment: i am using horizontal recycler View but it is taking too long to display the image

Comment: @user3913975  the  images may be of large size why cant you use Glide instead of Picasso because  glide loads images faster than picasso